# How do I insert an image as background in google sheets

Tags: image, google-sheets, background-image

I wanna insert an image as a background in google sheets. In Excel, it is so easy but Google sheets I didn't find any option, please help.

[image]

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 4):

you have 3 options how to insert an image:

- with [`IMAGE()`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9224754?hl=en) formula
- or with the UI like:

---

[image]

after that, you can make it as background only if you overlay it with Drawing:

[image]

which is not really a classical "image set as background" but that's the current limitation of google sheets